# make command won't work although makefile exists

Tags: server, gnu, parallels

I am trying to install GNU parallel on a remote server where I am ***not*** root. I downloaded it and at the moment this is how the directory looks:

```
aclocal.m4    config.h.in   COPYING  install-sh   missing  src
cc-by-sa.txt  configure     CREDITS  Makefile.am  NEWS
CITATION      configure.ac  fdl.txt  Makefile.in  README
```

when I used the command **./configure** I got this:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
```

when I type ls the directory now looks like this :

```
aclocal.m4    config.h     config.status  COPYING  ile          Makefile.in  README
cc-by-sa.txt  config.h.in  configure      CREDITS  install-sh   missing      src
CITATION      config.log   configure.ac   fdl.txt  Makefile.am  NEWS         stamp-h1
```

when I use the command **make** I get this:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Edit:

I have tried the few suggested answers listed  down below, and this is where I am right now:

```
~/parallel-20190822/src$ make

make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

~/parallel-20190822/src$ make install

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/olachhab/parallel-20190822/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/olachhab/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c parallel sql niceload parcat parset env_parallel env_parallel.ash env_parallel.bash env_parallel.csh env_parallel.dash env_parallel.fish env_parallel.ksh env_parallel.mksh env_parallel.pdksh env_parallel.sh env_parallel.tcsh env_parallel.zsh '/home/olachhab/bin'
make  install-exec-hook
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/olachhab/parallel-20190822/src'
rm /home/olachhab/bin/sem || true
ln -s parallel /home/olachhab/bin/sem
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/olachhab/parallel-20190822/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/olachhab/share/doc/parallel'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 parallel.html env_parallel.html sem.html sql.html niceload.html parallel_tutorial.html parallel_book.html parallel_design.html parallel_alternatives.html parcat.html parset.html parallel.texi env_parallel.texi sem.texi sql.texi niceload.texi parallel_tutorial.texi parallel_book.texi parallel_design.texi parallel_alternatives.texi parcat.texi parset.texi parallel.pdf env_parallel.pdf sem.pdf sql.pdf niceload.pdf parallel_tutorial.pdf parallel_book.pdf parallel_design.pdf parallel_alternatives.pdf parcat.pdf parset.pdf parallel_cheat.pdf '/home/olachhab/share/doc/parallel'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/olachhab/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 parallel.1 env_parallel.1 sem.1 sql.1 niceload.1 parcat.1 parset.1 '/home/olachhab/share/man/man1'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/olachhab/share/man/man7'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 parallel_tutorial.7 parallel_book.7 parallel_design.7 parallel_alternatives.7 '/home/olachhab/share/man/man7'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/olachhab/parallel-20190822/src'
```

in this link [http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README][1] I followed the full installation to get here, I tested the way they suggested: with this command:

```
parallel -j0 ping -nc 3 ::: qubes-os.org gnu.org freenetproject.org
```

and this is what I get:

```
Command 'parallel' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install moreutils
apt install parallel 

Ask your administrator to install one of them.
```

Comment: It seems the `Makefile` was output to the file `ile` given your `ls` output. No idea why that would happen, so you'd need to debug yourself on your remote system why.

Comment: @dobey please check the edit

Comment: GNU Parallel is now installed in ~/bin. So PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin and then you can use parallel. If you had followed my answer, it would already be set. All you needed to do was start a new shell.

Comment: @waffles123 The edit doesn't resolve the question of why the toplevel Makefile was created wrongly. It does show it's installed into a location which apparently is not in your `$PATH` though, as mentioned already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README):

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 67bd7bc7dc20aff99eb8f1266574dadb
12345678 67bd7bc7 dc20aff9 9eb8f126 6574dadb
$ md5sum install.sh | grep b7a15cdbb07fb6e11b0338577bc1780f
b7a15cdb b07fb6e1 1b033857 7bc1780f
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep 186000b62b66969d7506ca4f885e0c80e02a22444
6f25960b d4b90cf6 ba5b76de c1acdf39 f3d24249 72930394 a4164351 93a7668d
21ff9839 6f920be5 186000b6 2b66969d 7506ca4f 885e0c80 e02a2244 40e8a43f
$ bash install.sh
```

Comment: please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> config.status: creating **src**/Makefile

I suggest that you try:

```
cd src
```

Confirm the existence of the Makefile:

```
ls
```

If it is there as we suspect:

```
make
```

And proceed.

Comment: Did *make* complete correctly and cleanly? May we see the output? What does the README say about the install process? Is it something other than the usual configure, make, make install? Without root access, you will probably not be allowed to install.

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: It appears to have completed without error. I still doubt that you can install it on the system without root access.

Comment: please check the edit